# Font Design - Autokerning Technology?

Tags: fonts, typography, kerning

Aside from kerning all my glyph pairs by hand, is there a generally acceptable automated solution? I just used FontForge's autokerning feature, which seems like a very rough approximation at best.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't much around and everything what exists is far from being "a generally acceptable automated solution". The ones I know:

**Proprietary software**

http://ikern.com/k1/  (Service only)

http://fontmaster.nl/ (has a Module called KernMaster)

**Open source**

http://charlesmchen.github.io/typefacet/topics/autokern/index.html (looks dead)